# Is garbage collection times on tomcat better with many small instances than on 1 large instance?

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

Right now we have a single Tomcat instance on our server with about 55 gigs of memory assigned to it.  We are also running the G1 garbage collector.

We are running many hosts on the tomcat server, each host itself does not have a lot of traffic, but all of them together add up to a decent amount of traffic.  The G1 garbage collector ends up calling a mixed GC every 30 seconds or so for about 2 seconds (that is what our max pause time is configured to, which we know that is too high and plan on adjusting it).

My question is, if I split these hosts off in to 4 x 14 gig tomcat instances on the same machine, or say, 7 x 8 gig instances will it help make the garbage collection more efficient and eliminate the pauses or the need for G1 to mix GC as often.

In summary, will my garbage collections be more efficient on many small heaps than it is on one large heap?

Comment: There is unlikely to be a single right answer. You will have to benchmark with different configurations to find the sweet spot for your usage. Oracle made some tweaks to garbage collection in 8u40, so it is probably worth taking that. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u40-relnotes-2389089.html

Comment: We plan on doing that using new relic.  Everything was fine until we reached a certain amount of traffic on our server, then slowly the GC became an issue.   That is why I am wondering if part of the reason for our GC problems is that there is such a large amount of memory being used in a very large heap at any given time.  My theory is that by shrinking the heap and the amount of traffic proportionally, it should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's hard to give a Yes/No answer for this :)

Splitting your applications across multiple instances of tomcat will make them easier to maintain .

**Cons :-**

1. **Configuring Heap Sizes** - You may need to manually configure the heap sizes for each tomcat
   instance and that takes some testing to determine the sizes for each
   tomcat instance but you can go with your current assumptions of
   classifying your applications based on their traffic and allocating
   memory accordingly. For example, your application with the highest
   traffic significantly larger than other apps might be running in
   its' own tomcat instance with it's own fixed heap size of 2GB.
2. **Routing URLs** - Now that you're dividing applications between
   multiple tomcat instances, few URLs have to be routed to a tomcat
   instance listening on a different port which was not as issue earlier as
   all the requests always end up on a single tomcat instance.

**Pros :-**

1. **Reduced GC times** - Heavy traffic leads to more work and most probably  increases your object allocation rates, so if you run that application in a separate
   tomcat instance, GC in one application will not effect all the other applications as they
   have their own instances. Your heaps will be relatively small compared to a single 55gig heap and GC times will be reduced considerably.
2. **Reduced Footprint** - Now that you're splitting your instances, your individual tomcat
   heap sizes may come down below 32GB which will enable you to take advantage of
   Compressed Oops which might reduce the memory footprint of your
   applications.
3. **High Availability** - Let's say that your often visited application encountered
   `OutOfMemoryException` because of unexpected traffic, all the other
       applications are still running and you just need to restart/analyze
       only one application's heap dump, which makes things way easier than
       analyzing a 55 gig heap :)

So it's obvious that it has several advantages, but you should do it with caution :)

Comment: Yes, we definitely want to be careful.  And we will be gathering stats on which hosts are the highest traffic so we can move them to something with a little more power.

My gut tells me that setting things up with multiple tomcat instances (that could be spread over multiple servers) will give us the flexibility to put higher traffic hosts on their own servers or on a server with other lower traffic hosts who don't need all of the power of their instance.  Thank you for your answer, you are right, it is not a simple yes/no, but what you provided is exactly the type of information I need.

Comment: Glad to be of help.. In case this answers your question, mark it as answered :)

Comment: Another con is managing ports. If you have multiple instances of tomcat, they all must listen on different ports. This will require either using something like httpd to listen on port 80/443 and route the traffic to appropriate port for specific tomcat instance or all the consumers to know what port to connect to.

Comment: @BrettOkken.. Good point :) I've updated my answer to reflect your views but I think it's better to go with your 1st option of using httpd instead of informing customers because we don't have the flexibility to change ports in future in second case.